# Google sheets query inside select string in a where clause how to use reference cells with dates in them as filters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=QUERY(customers,"SELECT B, G, F, E, M WHERE F >= DATE '2020-6-1' AND F <= DATE '2020-6-7',0)
```

I have this string inside a Google Sheets Query.

I want to replace the two dates with a cell for each to simplify adjusting the dates every week at the cell and not the actual function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
=QUERY(customers,"SELECT B, G, F, E, M WHERE F >= DATE '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'  AND F <= DATE '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MMM-dd")&"'",0)
```

Change the cell references as needed. Depending on your locale you may have to change the commas in the formula to semi-colons.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your quick response. I've added your solution but seem to get Formula Parse Error.

Comment: Invalid date literal, date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Updated the formula.

Comment: Found the error, the cells where I have the dates stored were formatted as automatic not as date so it wasn't reading the content of the cell as a date. Figured out thank you.